# How to decode a JWT signature with a modulus/exponent

Tags: java, scala, jwt, rsa

I am trying to decode a JWT token signature, using modulus/exponent from a keycloak authentication server JWKS URL.

modulus/exponent are encoded as String (base64 url) , so here is my code to get the JWT secret key :

```
def secretKey: String = {

// modulus and publicExponent from keycloak /admin/jwks URL

val modulus = new BigInteger(1,Base64.getUrlDecoder.decode(Config.getString("jwks.modulus")))
val exponent = new BigInteger(1, Base64.getUrlDecoder.decode(Config.getString("jwks.publicExponent")))

val publicSpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent)

val factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA")

factory.generatePublic(publicSpec)

Base64.getUrlEncoder.encodeToString(key.getEncoded)
}


JwtCirce.decode(token, secretKey, Seq(JwtAlgorithm.RS256)) // <- fails
```

I am using the JwtCirce Scala lib to decode the token.

On the last line, I have the following error : **Last unit does not have enough valid bits**

Please note that if I don't check the signature, it works :

```
JwtCirce.decode(token, new JwtOptions(signature = false))
```

Comment: Can you share one sample token and the values of the public key part you get from the jwks?

Comment: "*Please note that if I don't check the signature, it works*" - what should not work as the header and the payload is **not encrypted** but only **Base64Url encoded**.

Comment: I can reproduce the verification failure (with my own data, i.e. JWT and key pair).  Currently `rsaSignature` passes the key Base64**url** encoded. If the encoding is changed to Base64, verification works on my machine! Alternatively, the key can be passed as `PublicKey` (_JwtCirce_ provides corresponding overloads). However, I could not reproduce your error message _Last unit does not have enough valid bits_. Thus, possibly there is an additional problem with your data. Btw, the name `rsaSignature` for the public key is confusing.

Comment: @Topaco thanks, I will try this ! I've also renamed rsaSignature

Comment: @Topaco I can't  decode using Base64 instead of Base64Url : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal base64 character 2d

Comment: @Topaco I have also changed my code to use the PublicKey  directly, thanks for the tip. Same error though

Comment: It seems to work now, with new tokens and using PublicKey . 
I will keep it open for now, because I'm not sure that the error will not appear with some tokens... And will close it if it still works